# PHP table field values into an array or multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I haven't actually came across this situation yet but i will probably have a need for it in the near future. In current frameworks or CMS like joomla I have noticed multiple parameters and values stored in 1 field within a database table. what would be the best way to extract these values as a key => value in an array? so say a field / column has (Joomla example):

```
show_title=1
link_titles=1
show_intro=blah blah blah
show_section=
link_section=
```

and so on ......

how would such break these up in a nice clean way? it also seems the entries have a new line to break apart each parameter. Is it actually possible to explode a /n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store values in json ecoded form.
In PHP you can use something like this:

[PHP json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Quoting Example from above page

```
<?php
$arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);    
$val= json_encode($arr);

//Insert $val in column
?>
```

To fetch the values use [PHP json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Joomla has built in methods from retrieving this kind of parameters. Pay a visit to [Joomla! Component Parameters](http://docs.joomla.org/Component_parameters)

Also, use documentation of [JParameter](http://docs.joomla.org/API15%3aJParameter)

Comment: Obviously there built in methods created by the joomla team... the point of the question is the best way to go about following these guidelines and implementing those methods into our own work. I have examined JParameter and JFactory etc. yet a bunch off there code is referencing alot off other classes which really isnt needed in my case, so my question is not based on Joomla, Joomla was used as an example. These methods arent hard to implement, Im just trying to find out the best way before i start 20 lines off code where it could be just a simple 2 line code.